# AWS S3 - How to restrict an IAM user to just a single bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been struggling with this for hours and cannot figure it out.

I've created a new user, duplicity, and I made a new bucket called bobs-house, and generated the following policy: (any numbers I'm not sure I should share are xxx'd out)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policyxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmtxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/duplicity"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bobs-house/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I go to the policy simulator, and run some tests. Sure enough, it says I can do whatever I want as user duplicity, but only on bobs-house. If duplicity tries to do anything involving other buckets, it's denied. Great!

Now I fire up my FTP client and connect to s3.amazonaws.com (using Transmit's S3 protocol of course, not FTP protocol), using duplicity's IAM access key and secret key. I get "access denied." I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Got it, thanks to John's answer below. I can use Transmit to connect and view only that bucket's contents, add files, etc. But duplicity (backup software) is complaining:

> PermanentRedirect. The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. bobs-house.s3.amazonaws.com

So I switch the formatting in duplicity's config to:

```
s3://bops-house.s3.amazonaws.com/test
```

And then I get this error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

My access key & secret key are definitely correct.

Comment: I didn't know AWS did ftp

Comment: Did you try `list-buckets` in the policy simulator?  Because I'm not sure what Transmit is doing under the hood, but it's quite possible it's trying some operation you don't have approval for that doesn't involve the specific bucket (in which case you really need to file a bug report with them).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to give Amazon S3 permissions to a specific user, it is better to create the policy **against the IAM User themselves**, rather than the bucket policy.

A **bucket policy** is good for assigning *universal* permissions, while a policy in **IAM** is good for giving permissions to specific Users or Groups of users.

See: [User Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html)

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. I edited my post.. there's one more issue